# Accessing objects returned by java script running in a webbrowser control from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, openlayers, openstreetmap

I would like to know how i can access properties of an object returned by a javascript function running inside a webbrowser control from within C#.

Here is the full context:

I'd like to create a C# mapping control based on OpenStreetMap's open layers javascript library. The OSM Map is displayed in a webpage shown inside the webbrowser element. I'm using InvokeScript in order to control the map by calling a simplified java script wrapper for the open layers library. Everything is working fine.

In the C# wrapper I'd like to implement a function returning the center coordinates of the Map currently beeing on display in the webbrowser control. So far i came only up with a pretty unelegant solution:

In my C# wrapper i have two functions that i need both in order to query the map center. First i have a function called GetCenter which uses InvokeScript to call a JavaScript function which in turn calls another C# function (SetCenterFromJScript) to set the map center in my C# wrapper:

```
public Coord GetCenter()
{
  object center = webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("set_center_in_wrapper");

  // I'm stuck here:
  Type type = center.GetType();
  PropertyInfo[] pi = type.GetProperties();

  // I already get the center as an object, but how can i access the
  // properties "lon" and "lat" directly so that i can get rid of m_center 
  // and SetCenterFromJScript alltogether?

  return m_center;
}

public void SetCenterFromJScript(double lon, double lat)
{
  m_center.lon = lon;
  m_center.lat = lat;
}
```

The Java script function is calling C# via the ObjectForScripting mechanism as shown here:

```
function set_center_in_wrapper()
{
  var center = map.getCenter().transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"), 
                                         new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"))

  window.external.SetCenterFromJScript(center.lon, center.lat);
  return center // <- useless at the moment since i don't know how to access the data from C#
}
```

At the moment the return value is useless, i'm using SetCenterFromJScript to submit the coordinates. How can i access the Properties "lon" and "lat" of center from C# directly?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `InvokeMember` to get the center's properties. Something like:

```
 object center = webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("set_center_in_wrapper");
 Type type = center.GetType();
 Int32 lon = (Int32) type.InvokeMember("lon", 
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, center, null);
 Int32 lat = (Int32) type.InvokeMember("lat", 
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, center, null);
```

I didn't check this code in this scenario before so you might need to play aroudn with the binding flags.

Comment: Thank you very much!. This is working with minor modifications: The type is double in my case and i have to use BindingFlags.GetProperty instead of BindingFlag.GetField.